Algebraic operations with functions represented as sets
While studying set theory and I had a problem at the stage of functions and various operations with them, which I couldn't find in the relevant literature. If I understand correctly, in set theory a function is a special case of a relation where no two ordered pairs can have the same first element. My question is how to give a rigorous definition of arithmetiical operations between function that are represented as a set of ordered pairs of numbers, such as ad-dition, subtraction, multiplication and division.
I am used to understanding functions as analytical expressions.
Let the first function f : $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ (-$\infty$; 4] be rep-resented by an analytical rule
$f(x)=-x^2+2x+3$.
And let the second function g : $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be represented by an analytical rule $g(x)= x^3+5$.
Then I can obviously write the product of these functions as the product of the corresponding analytical expressions, as follows:
$h(x) = (f*g)(x) = (-x^2+2x+3)*( x^3+5) = -x^5+2x^4+3x^3-5x^2+10x+15$
According to set theory, all three functions can be represented as sets(I will do this for some values of variable x):
$f=\{(-4,-21),(-3,-12),(-2,-5),(-1,0),(0,3),(1,4),(2,3),(3,0),(4,-5)\}$
$g=\{(-4,-59),(-3,-22),(-2,-3),(-1,4),(0,5),(1,6),(2,13),(3,32),(4,69)\}$
$h=\{(-4,1239),(-3,264),(-2,15),(-1,0),(0,15),(1,24),(2,39),(3,0),(4,-345)\}$
The problem is that in the case where I have sets of these functions, I do not understand how to correctly write an expression that would allow me to form set of ordered pairs of num-bers that look like a combination of two others. I can only write the result of this operation as a set. The best solution I found was to use set-builder notation but I'm not sure how correct it is.
Is there such a strict rule or operator in set theory that would connect two functions that are given in the condition and allow one to obtain another function in the form of a set of ordered pairs depending on the given arith-metic operation (addition, subtraction, multi-plication, division)?

Hi Max; before dropping the final migration vote, you should check out definitions bt recursion. This is how the basic arithmetical operations are typically defined in a set theoretical setting.
